# Is it possible to avoid SQL injection attacks when using a pure string?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database, sql-injection

I am currently interacting with a legacy SDK, which is used to control hand reader hardware. It is a commercial SDK and product, and thus there is no way to access the hardware other than through this SDK.

I am attempting to run SQL queries on the hand reader's database, and the SDK only provides one method for doing so, with the following signature:

```
handReader.QueryDB(string sqlStatement);
```

This thus implies that any query can be passed to that method in the form of a string. While this is simple, it immediately points towards possible SQL injection attacks.

I do not have access to the method's workings, thus cannot see whether any detailed SQL prevention goes on within it. Thus, I would like to find a way to paramaterise the string, similar to paramaterised queries utilising the `SqlCommand` class.

Is this possible?

Comment: In the good old days we escaped user data.

Comment: I don't think so. Prepared statements have to be supported by the SQL engine.

Comment: Surely you still have to build the string yourself to send into this method? Therefore you can sanitize all user input as best you can before creating the string and sending it

Comment: But, why does a heand reader have an SQL database and why would you put user-supplied information into it?

Comment: @iabbott - That's right, but as you pointed out - "as best you can". I always sanitize user input, but the idea behind paramaterised queries is an extra layer of protection and peace of mind :)

Comment: @BartFriederichs - It is used for HR purposes, i.e. employees clocking in and out. The user-supplied information is in cases where new employees are added, edited, etc.

Comment: @DotNET I guess then that it will be based entirely on how you're getting the data to create the string. If you **HAVE** to use this method, with no idea what is going on inside it, what you've done is about all you can do....

Comment: That's what I feared @iabbott - thanks for the info.

Comment: @DotNET Based on your HR comment above, the only data you're passing is from some kind of entry form for new employees? In that case, just limit the allowed entries to be alphanumeric...I don't think there is anything you can really do maliciously if you can't use any punctuation or symbols...

Comment: Thanks @iabbott - It's actually even simpler than that, as only developers pass such data, as the legacy software does not have a form. I guess I'm just trying to cater for any possible eventuality where a non-company developer gains access to the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implement a string format that works with names instead of numbers
Here's my sql string:

```
string sqlStr = @"select * from Table1 t1
where t1.field1 = @Field1 and IsActive = 1";

int F1 = 12; 
sqlStr = sqlStr.NamedStringFormatSQL(new
        {
            Field1 = F1
        });
```

And this is code for formatter:

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> AnonymousToDictionary(object value)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> dic = new Dictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        if (value != null)
        {
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor descriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(value))
            {
                object obj2 = descriptor.GetValue(value);
                dic.Add(descriptor.Name, obj2);
            }
        }
        return dic;
    }


   public static string NamedStringFormatSQL(this string aString, object replacements)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> keyValues = AnonymousToDictionary(replacements);
            foreach (var item in keyValues)
            {
                string val = item.Value == null ? "null" : item.Value.ToString();
                aString = aString.Replace("@" + item.Key, val);
            }
            return aString;

        }
```

Comment: This do no escaping, and thus, are vulnerable to sql injections. It doesn't even quote strings. And what if Field1="@Field2"? Such a simple loop would then become "t1.field1 = @Field2", and the next replace would place Field2 into field1.

Comment: I always pass user input as parameters to the query containing method, so at least data type will be checked, for the rest consider this method as a template and placeholder for further checking that can be done in NamedStringFormatSQL